# What is the difference between a slot and a method in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

What is the difference between a slot (a method declared in `slots` section) and a method in Qt (a method declared with Q_INVOKABLE keyword)? They both can be invoked using `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`, they are both accepted when connecting to a slot using `SLOT` macro, however when getting type of metamethod it can be returned either `QMetaMethod::Method` or `QMetaMethod::Slot`, so it seems that there is some difference for Qt?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only difference is whether the method is listed as a slot or as not-a-slot in the class's metadata. In both Qt 4 and Qt 5, connection to either a slot or an invokable succeeds:

```
#include <QObject>
struct Test : public QObject {
  Q_SLOT void slot() {}
  Q_INVOKABLE void invokable() {}
  Q_OBJECT
};

int main() {
  Test test;
  auto c1 = QObject::connect(&test, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)), &test, SLOT(slot()));
  auto c2 = QObject::connect(&test, SIGNAL(destroyed(QObject*)), &test, SLOT(invokable()));
  Q_ASSERT(c1);
  Q_ASSERT(c2);
}
#include "main.moc"
```

It's up to the user to decide how the difference between a slot and an invokable is interpreted. E.g. if you're exposing the slot list to the user in some way, you won't be exposing the invokable method list unless you choose to do so.

Comment: What is the "slot list"? How do you get it? Where is a situation where it would be useful?

Comment: @pooya13 I might be oversimplifying here, but I had found it useful when connecting signals to slots between two plugin DLLs and taking a regular pointer to function was impossible as at compile time it would "live" inside the not yet loaded DLL.

Answer (score 7):

The practical differences I know of:

- `Q_INVOKABLE` can have a return value, `slot` cannot return a value to the GUI thread.
- `Q_INVOKABLE` is called on the GUI thread and blocks the GUI thread. `slot`'s thread depends on which thread the `QObject` was created on, and therefore can be non-blocking.

So my rule of thumb is, use `slot` if there are no return values, otherwise use `Q_INVOKABLE`.

Comment: Slot can have a return value. It's just ignored if invoked by a signal, there's nothing to return it to.

Comment: Thanks @hyde. I have been away from C++/QML for a while but I think I meant to say `slot`'s cannot return value to the GUI thread when I wrote this.